# Procedure for getting a crypto exchange to freeze and apprehend a whale scammer?

Tags: etherscan, exchanges, privacy, scam, legal

Traced a wallet funneling embezzled funds to a wallet on a centralized exchange using the **peel-chain** strategy. It's accumulated thousands of stolen bitcoin for almost a decade and still is!

How to ask the exchange (Binance) to freeze or investigate that account? Most CEX's are very impersonal, running on anon wax, and ignore requests of any sort, having no phone numbers nor locations of their HQs. Which authorities and procedure please.

And have there been any successful restitution cases recently against whale scammers, whereby victims demanded the exchange to take action against their own client? It's one thing to apprehend the suspect, but another to get any of the stolen money returned to victims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it's difficult for individual investors to ask exchange such as Binance or CEX to freeze or investigate a whale scammer. Individual investors usually don't have enough power or authority to demand these centralized exchanges to do much. The government is the one that usually has enough power and authority to make such demands because they can shut centralized exchanges down if they don't comply with their jurisdictions. Centralized exchanges will usually comply because they want to keep their business running and thus will adhere to the orders by governments.

Whales scamming individual investors are more of an ethical issue but unless this ethical issue challenges the stability of the market to a level that interferes with the enforcement of the government, government usually will not interfere but will take note. If the issues are serious enough the government will step in but power will become centralized in the government's hands who, eventually, will interfere with decentralization, one of the core principles of blockchain.

Comment: Which or whose government do you speak of? Conflicts between anonymous whales and numerous victims across the world automatically signifies an International Law matter. If you mean the CEX's govt, they operate in numerous jurisdictions simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

A whale and scammer are not the same thing. It's also a false narrative that CEXs don't have some sort of procedure to report fraud or for agencies to ignore valid law requests.

Binance regularly adheres to valid law requests. The thing you haven't done is found any legal basis or bothered to put any process any motion and dismissed CEXs as uncooperative entities.

I worked with MTGOX when a phishing operator stole MTGOX accounts and sent funds out - they seized all his accounts and returned every penny to owners. So even small companies know how to operate within the law.

Comment: Are you going through all my questions and voting -1 just because I -1'd one of your answers, which lets be honest was pretty poor?

Comment: Others would find your question poorly structured too - no point in trying to make assumptions here. Let's be honest, a lot of your questions are poor too - they answer themselves and you get terminology wrong all the time.